# How to add a function to a function

Tags: javascript, cron, discord, discord.js, trello

I currently have a cron job function to send a message every morning at 7:00 am, and it works perfectly but now I want it to get the message from a Trello card and the Trello part works perfectly, but when I put them together it doesn’t work. Any ideas? Here what I have so far:

```
var job = new CronJob('01 15 18 * * *', function() {
        let listID = "5ec3fda8a26c384e44f063bb";
trello.getCardsOnListWithExtraParams(listID, "pos:top",
       function (error, trelloCard) {
        console.log('Found card:', trelloCard[0].name);
})
const wyrEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("❓**WOULD YOU RATHER**❓")
      .addField(
        "**THE WOULD YOU RATHER**", "test: " + trelloCard[0].name)
      .setDescription(
        " Top o' the mornin’ to ya! All throughout the night, I’ve been preparing a would you rather question for all of you! I can’t wait to see all of the answers you guys think of! "
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("Munchies Ice Cream", client.user.avatarURL)
      .setThumbnail("https://t4.rbxcdn.com/366f4da2e1924b6e4b0816086b485f05")
      .setColor("7ab7e2"); 
        const wyrthing = client.channels.get("688177088573997066")
  wyrthing.send(wyrEmbed)
    console.log('You will see this message every second')
},
  null,
    true,
    'America/New_York'
);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically tries to do this (in this order):

- Start getting the Trello card
- Send the embed using the (non-existent) Trello card
- *Later, when the Trello card has been retrieved*: Log "Found card: <card name>"

This is because `trello.getCardsOnListWithExtraParams` is an asynchronous function. You're getting the result `trelloCard` as a parameter to your callback function, but you are trying to access it outside the callback when you add a field to your embed.

Put this in your cron function:

```js
let listID = "5ec3fda8a26c384e44f063bb";
trello.getCardsOnListWithExtraParams(listID, "pos:top", function (error, trelloCard) {
  console.log('Found card:', trelloCard[0].name);
  const wyrEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("❓**WOULD YOU RATHER**❓")
    .addField("**THE WOULD YOU RATHER**", "test: " + trelloCard[0].name)
    .setDescription(
      " Top o' the mornin’ to ya! All throughout the night, I’ve been preparing a would you rather question for all of you! I can’t wait to see all of the answers you guys think of! "
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("Munchies Ice Cream", client.user.avatarURL)
    .setThumbnail("https://t4.rbxcdn.com/366f4da2e1924b6e4b0816086b485f05")
    .setColor("7ab7e2"); 
  const wyrthing = client.channels.get("688177088573997066")
  wyrthing.send(wyrEmbed)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to get this to work for such a long time and this just fixed everything, thank you!!